# EASY: How do I separate elements grabbed by class name using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm opening two links from links.txt and outputting to names.txt.

I'm trying to get rid of the word: "FEATURING" and add: ", " between the elements.

Current output:

```
FEATURING
Arietta AdamsIsiah MaxwellFEATURING
Vanessa VegaRichard Mann
```

Desired output:

```
Arietta Adams, Isiah Maxwell
Vanessa Vega, Richard Mann
```

My code:

```
one = open("links.txt", "r")

for two in one.readlines():
  driver.get(two)
  sleep(3)
  for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sceneColActors'):
    with open("names.txt", "a") as testtxt:
      testtxt.write(element.text)
```

Html:

```
<div class="sceneCol sceneColActors"> == $0
   <b>Featuring </b>
   <a href="/en/Arietta-Adams/58224" title="Arietta Adams">Arietta Adams</a>
   <span class="actorSeparator">, </span>
   <a href="/en/Isiah-Maxwell/34204" title="Isiah Maxwell">Isiah Maxwell</a>
```

[Here's a screenshot of the html just in case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezd0K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should try to get `a` tags separately. Try

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sceneColActors a')
```

instead of

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sceneColActors')
```

And now you can get all needed words separately and you just add delimiter `,` between them.

Comment: This was the piece. Thank you.